# Custom dynamic object panel for Windows Phone 7 application

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am currently working on an application for Windows Phone 7+ and am lost as to how to create a dynamic menu bar at the bottom of my application. When the user clicks on the bar at the bottom, it should act exactly like the [Application Bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLSAf.png) by sliding about halfway up the screen. I have tried multiple approaches and can't seem to replicate the behavior of the Application Bar.

Here is a screenshot of the custom object in question: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmObq.jpg

Again, when any one of the icons at the bottom is pressed, I want the entire bar to slide up as if the "..." on the Application Bar was pressed. Any feedback is welcome.

Thank you,
TiDe

Comment: I am not sure you want to do something that is already built-in.

Comment: What have you tried? What's the issue? How do your approaches fail to replicate the behavior of the application bar?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [PhoneFlipMenu](http://www.geekchamp.com/marketplace/components/phoneflipmenu)?
Maybe this is something that you need?